# To mod or not to mod pounds & pennies

Tags: java

Can this be done in a simpler way. I wanted to use MOD for my Pounds and Pennies, but I can't convert int to double.

I had to trick the console if you would, with formatting, but it isn't putting out a true decimal no.

Is my code the only way? Is my code the shortest way of doing this?

```java
public class Question4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int count = 0;
        int coins [] = new int [8];
        int [] pennies = {200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1};
        
        String [] coinTxt = {"£2 =","£1 =", "50p =", "20p =", "10p =", "5p =", "2p =", "1p ="};
        
        System.out.println("Enter your coins\n");
        
        for (int i = 0; i <coinTxt.length; i++) {
            System.out.print( coinTxt[i]+"\t");
            
            coins [i] = key.nextInt();
        }
        
        for (int i=0;  i <coins.length; i++) {
            //System.out.print(coins[i]);
            
            count = coins[i]*pennies[i]+count;
        }
        
        //System.out.print("\n\n"+count);
        
        System.out.print("\nTotal change is £"+count/100+".");
        
        System.out.print(count%100);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of “MOD”?

Comment: I fixed your code formatting for you this time. Study that so you’ll know next time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and see [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and other pages in the help center.

Comment: *"Can this be done in a simpler way"* Can *what* be done in a simpler way? You need to explain what your program is *intended* to do. If the code shown doesn't work as intended, you shouldn't rely on us to interpret the intention from the code. Then, explain why you think your code is not working as intended. Include examples. Each example should have input, expected output, and actual output. It also  helps to tell us what you have done to debug your code.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer ok got it, I`ll take the tour... I thought it was easy to read what I was trying to do, that is why I didn`t explain much I guess. I`ll make sure next time to add  more information.

Comment: @BasilBourque  MOD is for modulate. I thought I could round them up or down but I don`t think it works the same like with "time". Can`t see where you fixed the code, not sure how to access that.

Answer (score 1):

`double` math [introduces rounding errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) and it is hard to know when and how those rounding errors affect your math. There's a good reason for that: If I ask you to write '1 / 3' on a piece of paper with a pen, in decimal, you can't do it. You can write, maybe, 0.33333333333333 but you run out of room eventually and you are forced to round.

Your computer works the same way, except, it's binary, not decimal. Which means anything not nicely divisible in 2s has the '1/3' problem. For example, 1/10th isn't nicely divisible by 2. In decimal, it's '0.1', easy. In computerese, it's like 0.3333333 - it's not quite right. We can trivially witness some truly bizarro errors with it quite easily:

```
double v = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) v += 0.1;
System.out.println(1.0 == v);
```

That prints.. `false`. So, apparently then, 10 * 0.1 is not the same as 1.0, I guess.

That's `double` math errors for ya.

So, the lesson is simple: *If `double` is anywhere near anything related to finances, **you did it wrong***.

Hence, your mindset here is wrong. You seem to be labouring under the presumption that using ints/longs to do finance stuff and then using mods and division to print it is 'cheating' and that a 'proper' take is to use a `double`, but you have it *precisely the wrong way around*. It's `double` + finances that's cheating / wrong, and sticking with integer math which is correct.

Note that this matches the financial systems. You can't, generally, pay half a cent. The right way to do finance math is almost always to store atomic finance units in an `int` or `long`. For yen, that's yen. For bitcoin, it's satoshis. For dollars or euros its cents. For pounds, its pennies. You don't *want* to be able to represent half a cent.

Unless you do (it's rare, but it happens) where you either want a different atomic unit, or, `BigDecimal`, which doesn't error, but note that in bigdecimalese, `1/3` is an error (because you can't do that without error), unless you tell BD how to deal with it which is all very complicated. Don't do finance stuff with BD unless you really know what you are doing (and don't do finance stuff with `double`. ever).

### But your code is still broken

The primary issue is printing `x % 100` which could be, say 4 cents, which prints as 4, but you want it to print as 04. Here's the nice way to do that:

```
System.out.printf("\nTotal change is £%d.%02d", count / 100, count % 100);
```

`printf` is the print version of `String.format` - the first argument is a template string, which contains placeholders. Then the remaining arguments are the values for those placeholders. `%d` means 'a decimal (i.e. whole) number, and `%02d` is involving 2 'modifiers'. The 0 means: 0-pad it up if the value is smaller than the amount of 'room' for this parameter, and the '2' means: Use 2 or more characters to represent the value.

Hence, `String.format("%02d", 9)` is the string "09". Because we asked for at least 2 characters, and we asked to 0-pad it to ensure it's at least 2. It's what you want here.

Note that for negative numbers, `%` might not do what you want. `-5 % 100` is.. -5. Generally to render negative numbers with such a mod/division system, you isolate out the minus sign and print it, then print the rest as positive number. Hence, to be complete:

```
public String formatPennies(int pennies) {
  String minus = "";
  if (pennies < 0) {
    minus = "-";
    pennies = -pennies;
  }
  int pounds = pennies / 100;
  pennies = pennies % 100;
  return String.format("£%s%d.%02d", minus, pounds, pennies);
}
```

Comment: many thanks for that lengthy explanation, I really appreciate it., it really helps me understand better and helps with a better coding technique for sure. Many thanks

Comment: This is a good answer, but if you say that monetary amounts should use integer values representing the minor unit (pence, cents etc) you might want to also explain what to do when, for example, my local petrol station sells petrol at 152.95 pence per litre.

Comment: @k314159 I already do, in the paragraph that starts with __Unless you do__. The question isn't asking about petrol prices, hence, it merely needs to ensure the reader knows where to look when that's their actual need. At some point 'answer could be improved if it explains mostly unrelated issue ABC' means the answer balloons into 150 pages and has buried the actual thing the reader is looking for. I disagree that the answer would be improved if any further words are written about BD here.

Answer (score 0):

The `/` operator, when applied to operands that are both integral, does *integer division*. This means that the result is truncated to an integer value.

What you are doing in your code is not correct. Imagine the amount is 104. You print 104/100 which is 1, followed by 104%100 which is 4. So your output is "1.4" but you need it to be "1.04".

You can use floating-point division by casting at least one of the operands to `double`:

```
System.out.println("\nTotal change is £" + (double)count / 100);
```

or

```
System.out.println("\nTotal change is £" + count / 100.0);
```

This may work most of the time, but there is a risk (with different numbers) of getting more than 2 decimal places due to the fact that floating-point numbers are stored in binary, and therefore don't precisely represent decimal floating points. You should therefore use a formatter to limit your output to 2dp:

```
System.out.printf("\nTotal change is £%.2f%n", count / 100.0);
```

However, as you get more advanced with Java, you should learn to use the `BigDecimal` class, which is more appropriate when dealing with monetary amounts.

Comment: double math has rounding errors and therefore is __entirely__ inappropriate for anything cash-related. This answer 'works', but misleads, and is therefore dangerous. Don't do any of this stuff.

Comment: @rzwitserloot this is a beginner's exercise, not a financial application. I did say at the end that they should eventually learn to use BigDecimal. By the way, most accountants use Excel, and Excel uses floating point.

Comment: @k314159 Many thanks to you too for the help and guidance and code. I`ll definitely study BD for the future.

Comment: @k314159 Indeed, an exercise. It's not useful to learn techniques that aren't ever appropriate. My comment stands.